# Determine the number of bits before receiver misses a bit

Tags: communication, data

A transmitter sends 100 bits per second but the receiver's clock runs too slowly causing it to measure once every 0.0107 seconds.  How many bits are measured in a row before the receiver misses a bit?

I have considered r=100bps and t_miss= 0.0107 and compute the time as 1-t_miss in order to determine the number of bits before a receiver misses a bit. Can anyone clarify me about this?

Comment: I have considered r=100bps and t_miss= 0.0107 and compute the time as 1-t_miss in order to determine the number of bits before a receiver misses a bit. can anyone clarify me about this? thanks

Comment: After posting, you can edit your question to add more information.

Comment: It is a good idea to update your question with extra information, and not bury it in comments, to help the community understand what you are asking. This ensures we are all on the same page. Please read [help] for guidance on asking good questions.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum sampling time to get the whole message is \$ 1/100 \$ or 10mS. Since the sampling time is 10.7ms a bit will be missed as soon as the samples line up at the end of bit 1 and the beginning of bit 3. The best scenario is when a sample lads at the beginning of a bit. Every following sample is then off set by 0.7ms until the sample strattles a bit. This would happen when the accumulated offset exeeds the sample time \$ 10/0.7 \$ or 14.28. This implies that the 15th bit will be missed.

Comment: Or, of course, if the start condition was right at the end of a bit, it would miss the 1st bit. For random placement, the average is about 7 1/2.

Comment: But what happens, If we make an initial assumption that the first bit is measured exactly in the center of the bit time?

Comment: @AnnonymousXYZ Then it would take half the time to miss the bit. So it would take half the bits, the 8th bit would be missed.